# Why does this unrelated error happen when I try to setup Windows 8 settings?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, application-settings

I have a few lines of code that have worked fine for months, and now suddenly they do not work and I get a very strange error.  Here is the function in question:

```
public void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane settingsPane, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs eventArgs) {
        UICommandInvokedHandler handler = new UICommandInvokedHandler(OnSettingsCommand);
        SettingsCommand appSettings = new SettingsCommand("appSettings", "アプリ内設定", handler);
        eventArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(appSettings);
}
```

Naturally, this gets called in response to the `SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested` event.  The error happens on the second line and is as follows:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

If I continue the app, then another exception comes:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Object in an IPropertyValue is of type 'String', which cannot be converted to a 'Guid'.

What is going on here?  As you can see I'm not using any GUID values anywhere.

Comment: As a point of disambiguation, "second line" is referring to `SettingsCommand appSettings = new SettingsCommand("appSettings", "アプリ内設定", handler);`, correct?  The first param is supposed to be an `Object` (but the documentation doesn't seem to list anything about restrictions, and the samples use strings too), maybe try passing a guid?  Or perhaps it's trying to construct a guid from the label, and the process doesn't play nice with non-ascii characters?  Does it work if you substitute a different label?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You were on the money.  If I pass a GUID as the first parameter it works just fine.

Comment: ... guess I'm posting that as an answer then, unless somebody has an explanation of _why_ a guid is now required...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the [documentation lists no restrictions, and all samples use strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingscommand.aspx), the first parameter is listed as taking `Object` - it's possible this now is simply set to require a giud.

Interestingly, it looks like this has been [reported to Microsoft as a bug in the OS](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/798084/invalidcastexception-with-first-parameter-of-settingscommand-of-type-string-windows-store-apps).  No idea what the resolution is going to be.

Comment: Just as an embarrassing tidbit, this exception seems to be handled internally.  It was just causing an exception breakpoint.  The program continues to run fine.  I assumed since an exception breakpoint was reached that the program would fail but it doesn't.

Comment: Could be a temporary fix of some sort.... I'd hope the permanent one doesn't need that much overhead.